# ¿Como separar resultados de consultas en arreglos individuales?

Tags: php, array

Me encuentro realizando consultas a una base de datos pasando como parámetros de consulta diferentes fechas que se encuentran en un arreglo, para ello utilizo un ciclo que depende del tamaño del arreglo de fechas, y dentro de este hago la consulta y los resultados los inserto en un arreglo. Sin embargo me interesa separar los resultados de cada consulta en un arreglo individual.

Por ejemplo consulto datos de los días 1, 2, 3 de octubre de 2017, entonces tengo un arreglo con esas fechas.

```
ArrayFechasIni([0] => 2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z[1] => 2017-10-02T00:00:00.000Z[2] => 2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z)

ArrayFechasFin([0] => 2017-10-01T23:59:59.000Z[1] => 2017-10-02T23:59:59.000Z[2] => 2017-10-03T23:59:59.000Z)
```

El ciclo que utilizo es el siguiente.

```
$Datos = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrFechasIni); $i++){        
    $datos = $generalOp->consultaFechasMulti($param1, $arrFechasIni[$i], $arrFechasFin[$i], $param4);
    array_push($Datos, $datos);

}
```

Lo que obtengo es un arreglo con los datos obtenidos a partir de esas fechas, pero esos datos están juntos y lo que necesito es que se separen, en este caso en 3 arreglos. Intente insertar cada resultado de la consulta en otro arreglo, pero teniendo como clave el indice del ciclo, algo como esto

```
$Datos = array();
$DatosFinal = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrFechasIni); $i++){        
    $datos = $generalOp->consultaFechasMulti($param1, $arrFechasIni[$i], $arrFechasFin[$i], $param4);
    $DatosFinal[$i] = array_push($Datos, $datos);
}
```

Pero esto solo me devuelve el siguiente arreglo

```
ArrayDatosFinal([0] => 1[1] => 2[2] => 3)
```

Yo espero obtener lo siguiente

```
ArrayDatosFinal([0] => (Conjunto de datos de la primer consulta)[1] => (Conjunto de datos de la segunda consulta)[2] => (Conjunto de datos de la tercer consulta)
```

Espero que me puedan sugerir alguna solución ante esto, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas `array_push`.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$DatosFinal = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrFechasIni); $i++){        
    $datos = $generalOp->consultaFechasMulti($param1, $arrFechasIni[$i], $arrFechasFin[$i], $param4);
    $DatosFinal[$i] = array($datos);
}
```

Comment: Funciona bien, solo un detalle y es que al poner `$DatosFinal[$i] = array($datos)`. Genera 3 arreglos con el mismo contenido, es decir copia en cada indice de `$DatosFinal` el resultado de la consulta. En cambio escribiéndolo como `$DatosFinal[$i] = $datos`. Separa los resultados de cada consulta en cada indice del arreglo

Answer (score 0):

puedes solo aplicar el array_push a tu variable $DatosFinal

revisa si $datos trae información

Ejemplo:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrFechasIni); $i++){        
    $datos = $generalOp->consultaFechasMulti($param1, $arrFechasIni[$i], $arrFechasFin[$i], $param4);
    array_push($DatosFinal, $datos);
}
```